Experiments on the effect of pruning a tree on water uptake and soil drying
Having a street tree close to my property and being concerned at the risk of subsidence, I am trying to understand whether and to what extent pruning of the tree might help to reduce the risk (I appreciate that other factors - tree species, soil type - are also important). From an online search I found a number of sources offering an opinion, but it was not so easy to find advice based on scientific experiment.
However, I came across the report Controlling water use of trees to alleviate subsidence risk (2004) describing a project led by a consortium including East Malling Research, the University of Cambridge, and others. This describes experiments in which two pruning techniques, crown-reduction and crown-thinning, were applied to trees over a period of years, and measurements were undertaken of the effects on transpiration and soil drying. The results broadly suggested that pruning was not a very effective method of reducing soil drying.
Crown-reduction, reducing the volume of a tree while preserving its shape, was found to reduce total water use of a tree in the year of pruning. Soil drying was also reduced in the year of pruning, but only to a small extent, and not at all in the following year unless the reduction was severe. It was also found that crown-reduction: a) led to re-growth with larger leaves arranged closer together; b) these leaves had a greater capacity to lose water.
Crown-thinning, removal of some lateral branches while preserving the overall size of the tree, was found not to reduce soil drying.
A limitation of the study was that the experiments on pruning were undertaken on just two species, wild cherry and London plane.
Question Have any subsequent experiments on the same or other tree species either confirmed or differed from these findings?

The obvious questions here are when was the tree planted and how big is it? The risks would be quite different for different trees I would have thought because of the different sizes, transpiration rates etc.

@bob1  About 12 years ago, and about 10 metres high.  But I mentioned the tree close to my property just as part of the background to my question about experiments on the effect of pruning trees.
